# If $|f'(x)| \leq c|f(x)|$ for all $x \in (0,1)$ then $f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, proof-verification, continuity

Question:   Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real valued continuous function which is differentiable on $(0,1)$, and satisfies $f(0)=0$. Suppose there exists a $c \in (0,1)$ such that $|f'(x)| \leq c|f(x)|$ for all $x \in (0,1)$. Show that $f(x)=0$.

Solution attempt:

$f$ being continuous at $x=0$, for a given $\epsilon >0$ $\exists$ a $\delta>0$, such that $|f(x)|< \epsilon$ whenever $x \in [0, \delta) \cap [0,1]$.

Now, consider $|f'(h)|=|\lim_{k \to 0}\frac{f(h+k)-f(h)}{k} |\leq |cf(h)| \implies \lim_{ \ k \to 0} |f(2h)| \leq |f(h)|[1+ c|k|] $ Being continuous at $x=0$, $\lim_{h \to 0} f(h) = f(0) = 0 \implies f(2h) = 0$ [by applying $|f(2h)| \leq |f(h)|(c|k|+1) \ $].

In this manner, let us partition the interval $[0,1)$ into $n$ subintervals of length $h$ each. As the length $h \to 0$, $n \to \infty$, and recursively, we get $|f(rh)| \leq |f(h)|(c|k|+1)^r \ $. Hence, finally for all $r$, we get $f(rh)=0$. By continuity, we can safely say, for all $x$ in those respective subintervals, $f(x)=0$. Again, by continuity, we have $\lim_{ x \to 1} f(x) = 0$.

Hence, $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $[0,1]$.

Comment: The third line in your attempt does not make sense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy which is?

Comment: I am referring to $|f'(x)|=|\lim \frac {f(h+h)-f(h)} h|$

Comment: Oh no!!!! I meant $f'(h)$

Comment: Still makes no sense. $|f'(h)|=|\lim_{k\to 0} \frac {f(h+k)-f(k)} k|$. Don't mix variables.

Comment: Can you please point out why?

Comment: You cannot use the same variable in your limit $(h)$ and the value of $f'$, they have to be "independent" of one another

Comment: I see my mistake now. Any other corrections?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Did not quite understand your question!?

Comment: It is actually from an entrance exam. I am not sure about "mathematical contexts" though

Answer (score 6):

Let $M$ be the sup norm of $f$. Let us prove by induction that $|f(x)| \leq \frac{c^nMx^n}{n!}$. 
If $n=0$, this is obvious.

Let $n \geq 0$ be such that $|f(x)| \leq \frac{c^nMx^n}{n!}$ for each $x$.

Then $|f’(x)| \leq \frac{c^{n+1}Mx^n}{n!}$ for each $x$.

Since $f(0)=0$, integration yields the desired inequality.

Now,  the $RHS$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$, thus $f=0$ (note that $c<1$ is unimportant).

Comment: Can you please check out mine?! Correcting the mistakes will help me immensely.

Comment: Ok: what does the inequality just after the first $\Rightarrow$ mean?

Comment: I used the fact that $||a|-|b||≤|a-b|$ and $k$ approaches $0$

Comment: No, you did not. Because this inequality does not mean anything. $k$ is defined on the right hand side but not on the left hand side, for instance.

Comment: Why is that so?

Comment: What number is $\lim_{k \rightarrow 0}\,|f(2h)|$?

Comment: The value is independent of $k$; on the other side of inequality, I did not mention $k \to 0$

Comment: I left $k$ there. Does it count wrong?

Comment: I suggest that you rewrite carefully your proof by replacing all the limits by their rigorous definitions, with the proper quantification and dependencies between variables. If there is no flaw, it should work out very cleanly — else you have a problem.

Comment: For your previous comment which I had not seen: it is not a matter of counting wrong, it is a matter of having an undefined variable in an inequality.

Comment: Is my approach towards the solution at all viable?

Comment: To be brutally honest, I don’t think so. It seems to me to be very deeply flawed owing to it not manipulating limits with the necessary rigor. However, I cannot prove that there is no proof that borrows some part of your ideas, so ... ;)